# A vertically centered equation number on a multline environment

Tags: equations, numbering, vertical-alignment, amsmath, multline

The `multline` environment does exactly what I want in splitting a long formula between lines by utilizing the horizontal space to the fullest. (I don't want the alignment features of the `align` environment.)

The problem is, I want to vertically center the equation number, as opposed to making it appear on the second line (as it does by default).

How do I do this?

Comment: I thought that maybe `\raisetag` could help, but it doesn't have any effect if the tag was not shifted from it's natural position...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you want is the `multlined` environment provided by `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}
a+b+c+d+e+f+{}\\
g+h+i+j
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there some update to have this output without `mathtools`, not necessarily aligning something?

Comment: @Sigur `multlined` is only available with `mathtools`.

Comment: multlined doesn't use all the horizontal space as multline does. there is some alternative more similar to multline?

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this:

```
\begin{equation}\label{xx}
\begin{split}
 a&= b+c-d\\
  & \quad +e-f\\
  &= g+h\\
  &= i
\end{split}
\end{equation}`
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is really just an addendum to/augmentation of the answer provided by @Thiago on the use of a `split` environment within an `equation` environment to get the vertical centering of the equation number.

- Normally, one uses the `split` environment to align successive lines on a single common point -- frequently, not necessarily, an `=` sign.
- However, by leaving off the align symbol, `&`, entirely from two (or more) consecutive lines, the resulting lines will simply be centered, one line after the other.
- Other alignment possibilities exist too. For example, the following code,

  ```
  \begin{equation} \begin{split}
  a+b+c+{}&d=\\
  &e+f+g+h
  \end{split} \end{equation}
  ```

  serves to have the `e` of the second line be placed exactly below the `d` of the first line.