# How to number two-line function definitions

Tags: equations, numbering

Lets say we have a two line function definition, for example, a translation

```
\begin{align}
    t_{p,q}\text{ : }&\mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \\
    &(x,y) \longmapsto (x+p, y+q) \notag
\end{align}
```

What/how is the correct way of numbering this? I personally just number the first line, but is it possible to have this number vertically centred? Or is there a better way?

Comment: You're probably looking for [How to get only one vertically centered equation number in align environment with two equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13396/5764) (also [A vertically centered equation number on a `multline` environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61195/5764)).