# Vertically aligned equation number with underbrace

Tags: equations, numbering, vertical-alignment, amsmath, multline

I would like to vertically aling an equation number for the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{aligned}
a &= b \\
  &= \underbrace{d+e}_{\substack{\text{Long}\\\text{text}}}
\end{aligned}
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}
a+b+c+d+e+f+{}\\
g+h+i+\underbrace{i+j}_{\substack{\text{Long}\\\text{text}}}
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

In both cases `underbrace` increases the size of the second line and thus, the equation number is not exactly between the two lines. How do I fix this?

This question can be understood as a follow up question of [A vertically centered equation number on a multline environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61195/a-vertically-centered-equation-number-on-a-multline-environment).

[image: Result of working example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, but requires some manual intervention.  The `\underbrace` can be `\smash`ed to align the equation number as you want.  But then, some `\vspace` needs to be added or the thing following the equation will sit too high.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{aligned}
a &= b \\
  &= \smash{\underbrace{d+e}_{\substack{\text{Long}\\\text{text}}}}
\end{aligned}
\end{align}
\vspace*{3ex}
\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}
a+b+c+d+e+f+{}\\
g+h+i+\smash{\underbrace{i+j}_{\substack{\text{Long}\\\text{text}}}}
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\vspace*{3ex}

Next line
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I accept this as a sufficient workaround because it only occurs at limited places in my document.

Comment: I think a more general answer could include the following: Always align in the middle of the two inner lines for an even number of lines. Always align to the center of the middle line for an odd number of lines.

Comment: @Lukas Such advice is good.  The problem arises because the package algorithms don't/can't always follow that advice without some "help", if abnormalities are introduced in the layout of the multi-line entity.  In this case, the `\underbrace` constitutes such an abnormality.